# If I am using ref inside useLayoutEffect, do I need to check add a check ref.current to see if ref is set?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I know that the ref is not available during the initial render, but it is available after the initial render has been completed. So, ref.current will always be available in the useEffect hook. However, I am confused whether ref will be set when the useLayoutEffect is called?

```
const MyComp = () => {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) //is this condition necessary?
    {
      //do something
    }
  }, []);
  return <div ref={ref}></div>;
};
```

Comment: No, thats not needed

Comment: having the condition is good in case you decide to make it render conditionally in the future. also, you'll need the check if you're using TS